# Error with variables declared using self

Tags: python, object-oriented-analysis

I have this code that pulls in each line off a text file like this line:

`13797906 23 n 04 flood 0 inundation 0 deluge 0 torrent 0 005 @ 13796604 n 0000 + 00603894 a 0401 + 00753137 v 0302 + 01527311 v 0203 + 02361703 v 0101 | an overwhelming number or amount; "a flood of requests"; "a torrent of abuse"`

and it is giving me errors with how the variables are declared. The code below is shortened as it is too long to post here.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from rdflib import URIRef, Graph
from StringIO import StringIO

class Wordnet():

    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = Graph()
        self.before_at = ''
        self.after_at = ''
        self.word_part = ''
        self.gloss_part = ''
        self.lex_filenum = ''
        self.synset_offset = ''
.............more declarations(too long to add here).....

    def process_file(self):
        self.file = open("new_2.txt", "r")
        return self.file

    def line_for_loop(self, file):
        for line in file:
            self.split_pointer_part(line)
            self.split_word_part(line)
            self.split_gloss_part(line)
            self.process_lex_filenum(word_part)   ###error starts here on line 48
            self.process_synset_offset(word_part)
.............more methods(too long to add here).....

    def split_pointer_part(self, line):
        self.before_at, self.after_at = line.split('@', 1)
        return self.before_at, self.after_at    

    def split_word_part(self, line):
        self.word_part = line.split()
        return self.word_part

    def split_gloss_part(self, line):
        self.gloss_part = line.strip().split('|')
        return self.gloss_part

    def process_lex_filenum(self, word_part):
        self.lex_filenum = word_part(1)
        return self.lex_filenum

    def process_synset_offset(self, word_part):
        self.synset_offset = word_part[0]
        return self.synset_offset

............plus more................

def print_graph(self, graph):
        print graph.serialize(format='nt')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wordnet = Wordnet()
    my_file = wordnet.process_file()
    wordnet.line_for_loop(my_file)   ###line 225
    wordnet.print_graph(graph)
```

When I try to run this file I get this error

```
File "wordnet.py", line 225, in <module>
    wordnet.line_for_loop(my_file)
  File "wordnet.py", line 48, in line_for_loop
    self.process_lex_filenum(word_part)
NameError: global name 'word_part' is not defined
```

Line 48 and 225 are shown in block comments above.
I don't know if it is some way I have the self variables declared or the way I pass them into each method or even how it is called in `__main__` but i just dont know what I have done wrong here. I am fairly new to python so some of this is complicated to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"NameError: global name 'word_part' is not defined" is telling you that python cannot find a global variable named "word_part" so you would need to replace word_part with self.word_part on line 48.

Comment: ok so I have that changed and now i am getting this:- `self.lex_filenum = word_part(1)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: from what i see you have a list somewhere and you are trying to access said list with () brackets instead of [] brackets

Answer (score 1):

The error is not with a `self. ...`. It is with the global variable `world_part`:

```
File "wordnet.py", line 225, in <module>
    wordnet.line_for_loop(my_file)
  File "wordnet.py", line 48, in line_for_loop
    self.process_lex_filenum(word_part)
NameError: global name 'word_part' is not defined
```

Where did `world_part` come from?

- if it is really **global variable** it should be defined outside of the class:

  ```
  wold_part = this_or_that # initialize

  class Wordnet():
      def __init__(self):
          ...

      def line_for_loop(self, file):
          ...
          self.process_lex_filenum(word_part) # use
  ```
- if it is a **module variable**, that is a variable defined if the global scope of an other module, you should import it:

  ```
  from my_world_module import world_part # import

  class Wordnet():
      def __init__(self):
          ...

      def line_for_loop(self, file):
          ...
          self.process_lex_filenum(word_part) # use
  ```
- if it is an **instance variable**, you should reference it from *self*:

  ```
  class Wordnet():
      def __init__(self):
          self.world_part = this_or_that # initialize

      def line_for_loop(self, file):
          ...
          self.process_lex_filenum(word_part) # use
  ```

Comment: So for each line of the text file I pull in the variables will change, so they have to be usable in the class but not outside it, what do you reccommend then?